# Подстановка значения переменной в f-строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Помогите пожалуйста.
`f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ:'`
`f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x}'`
Мне нужно чтобы вместо {0}, ставился класс, в зависимости от значения.
Если 24, то класс `Real time class`.
Если 12, то класс `High class`.
Как это можно сделать?
При запуске мы добавляем значения через команды `add1 24`, затем `add2 13`. И запускаем через команду `start`. И в этой строке мы получаем что в `f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'` вместо `{x}` ставится *24*. А мне нужно чтобы кроме этого еще на месте, где стоит `{0}` ставился нужный класс. При значении `{x}` *24* это будет класс `Real time class`, если `{x}` *13*, то `High class` и так далее
`{x}` берется из

```
idx = {} 
    
for x in idx:
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- config: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import queue
import threading
import time


class QueueThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self) -> None:
        print(f'Старт потока {self.name}')
        process_queue()
        print(f'Завершение потока {self.name}')


def process_queue():
    while True:
        try:
            x = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process1 = idx[x]
            y = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process2 = idx2[y]
        except queue.Empty:
            return
        else:
            print_factors(x, y, process1, process2, res_list)

        time.sleep(1)


def print_factors(x, y, process1, process2, res_list):
    try:
        for g in results:
            res_list = g[x]
    except KeyError:
        res_list = []
    current_res = []
    st = time.time()
    try:
        begin = drop_list[x]
    except KeyError:
        begin = 1
    for i in range(begin, x + 1):
        current = time.time()
        if i == x:
            del idx[x]

            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ:\n '
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ГОТОВНОСТЬ, в потоке \n'
                             f'появился процесс PID:2 с более высоким приоритетом: \n \n'
                             f'Значение приоритета процесса PID:1 = {x} \n'
                             f'Значение приоритета процесса PID:2 = {y} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ: \n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {y} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:2 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние ОЖИДАНИЕ \n '
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {y} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ \n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:1 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние ОЖИДАНИЕ \n '
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            break


def entry_get(event):
    global idx, cm_list, ps_queue
    command = en1.get()
    term.insert(END, f'# {command} \n')
    cm_list.append(command)
    en1.delete(0, 'end')
    if command == 'exit':
        root.destroy()
    elif command.startswith('add1 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('add2 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx2[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command == 'clear':
        term.delete(0.0, END)
    elif command == 'start':
        thread1 = QueueThread('A')
        thread1.start()
    elif command == 'list':
        term.insert(END, f'Список приоритетов, состовляющих алгоритм планирования \n')
        for i in idx:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
        for i in idx2:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
    elif command == 'help':
        term.insert(END, f'"add1 УРОВЕНЬ ПРИОРИТЕТА" - добавляет уровень приоритета процесса 1.')
        term.insert(END, f'"add2 УРОВЕНЬ ПРИОРИТЕТА" - добавляет уровень приоритета процесса 2.')
        term.insert(END, f'"list" - выводит список приоритетов, для алгоритма планирования. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"clear" - очищает терминал. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"help" - выводит список команд. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"start" - запускает алгоритм планирования. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"exit" - выход. \n')
    else:
        term.insert(END, f'{command} -- неизвестная комманда, используйте "help". \n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = {}
    idx2 = {}
    res_list = []
    results = []
    drop_list = {}
    cm_list = []
    ps_queue = queue.Queue()
    for x in idx:
        ps_queue.put(x)
    for y in idx2:
        ps_queue.put(y)
    r = str('Real time class')
    h = str('High class')
    a = str('Above normal class')
    n = str('Normal class')
    b = str('Below normal class')
    i = str('Idle class')
    info = str('неопределен')

    if idx == 24:
        print(r)
    elif idx == 13:
        print(h)
    elif idx == 10:
        print(a)
    elif idx == 8:
        print(n)
    elif idx == 6:
        print(b)
    elif idx == 4:
        print(i)
    if idx2 == 24:
        print(r)
    elif idx2 == 13:
        print(h)
    elif idx2 == 10:
        print(a)
    elif idx2 == 8:
        print(n)
    elif idx2 == 6:
        print(b)
    elif idx2 == 4:
        print(i)

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry('570x400')
    root.title("Подсистема управления процессами с алгоритмом планирования на основе абсолютных приоритетов")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    lb1 = Label(text='Командная строка:', width=0)
    lb2 = Label(text='Терминал:', width=0)
    en1 = Entry(width=68, bg='black', fg='white')
    term = Text(bg='black', width=65, height=19, fg='white')

    en1.bind('<Return>', entry_get)
    en1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: print(idx))

    lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=5)
    lb2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    en1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    term.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что у вас python 3.5? Если мне не изменяет мой склероз, в 3.5 f-строки еще не были реализованы...

Comment: Я чего-то не понял... `idx = {}` - это таки словарь? Или таки число: `if idx == 24`?

Comment: Всем спасибо, уже решили вопрос. 3.5 случайно поставил. idx = {} это словарь в который передаются значения 24 или 13 или 10 и тд

Comment: Я же вчера на точно такой же вопрос тут отвечал. Это вы его задавали?

Comment: Да, но я не совсем понял что делать с этой строкой class_str = class_info.get(idx, 'неопределен') в итоге у меня выдавало ошибку. Только сейчас понял что я делал не так. Вам спасибо, я тот ответ тоже пометил как решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так и выводите в строке нужное вам значение, зачем вы 0 выводите?

Создайте, например, себе словарь где для каждого `x` прописано название класса, и выводите на печать:

```
class_grades={13:"Hight class", 24:"Real time class"}
x=13
print(f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, значение - {x} \n \n')
# Класс приоритета: Hight class, значение - 13 
x=24
print(f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, значение - {x} \n \n')
# Класс приоритета: Real time class, значение - 24
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли. Я просто совсем не знал как это делать.